# My ElasticSearch snapshot indices directory are not deleted when I delete the Snapshot

Tags: elasticsearch

In my application, we use daily indices inside ElasticSearch.
Each day, we create a Snapshot of the previous day, in our Snapshot repository.

After some days, we delete the indices of the Elastic, and after some days again, we delete the Snapshot.

However, when I go into `$my_snapshot_repositories_path/indices` directory, I still see all the indices that have been Snapshoted, whereas they are not anymore returned by Snapshot list API (and the meta-XXX and snap-XXX files are not present on the filesystem for theses Snapshots).
However, all the indices directory contains no data, just 5 empty directory with name 1, 2, etc.

This is my repository file hierarchy content:

```
index
indices
meta-backup_flux-2017.03.24.dat
meta-backup_flux-2017.03.25.dat
meta-backup_flux-2017.03.26.dat
```

And this is the indices directory file hierarchy content:

```
flux-2017.03.23
flux-2017.03.24
flux-2017.03.25
flux-2017.03.26
```

And their content (all these directories are empty):

```
drwxr-x--- 2 4096 Mar 31 12:00 0
drwxr-x--- 2 4096 Mar 31 12:00 1
drwxr-x--- 2 4096 Mar 31 12:00 2
drwxr-x--- 2 4096 Mar 31 12:00 3
drwxr-x--- 2 4096 Mar 31 12:00 4
```

Finally, when I do a `du -sh *` in the indices directory, I see that all my deleted indices weight is 24KB (size of 6 directory on Linux). The not deleted indices weight is ~40MB.

For information, my Elastic Search indices used for searching are stored in another place on the computer.

Am I doing something wrong?

My ElasticSearch version: `2.4`

And this is the way I create and delete Snapshot:

Snapshot creation:

```
curl -s -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X PUT -d "{\"indices\": \"flux-2017.03.23\", \"ignore_unavailable\": false, \"include_global_state\": false}" http://0.0.0.0:9200/_snapshot/backup_flux/backup_flux-2017.03.23?wait_for_completion=true
```

Snapshot deletion:

```
curl -s -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X DELETE http://0.0.0.0:9200/_snapshot/backup_flux/backup_flux-2017.03.23
```

Regards.

Comment: you mean you still see indices after deleting snapshots? that looks fine to me, you deleted snapshot, not the original index

Comment: Hello, I mean I still see indices inside my snapshot repository, I don't speak about my indices that are used for the search. In fact, for me, when I create a snapshot, ES copy the index content inside the snapshot repository. So when I want to delete the snasphot, then indices inside snapshot repository that are not used by other snapshot must be deleted, else the snapshot repository size would always grow up.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally speaking, it should... But a quick glance throught the ES Docs shows the follows:

A repository can be deleted using the following command:

DELETE /_snapshot/my_backup

When a repository is deleted, Elasticsearch only removes the reference to the location where the repository is storing the snapshots. The snapshots themselves are left untouched and in place.

Comment: The OP is deleting the *snaphot*, not the snapshot repo